# Show automation missing from tool bar - LogicProX

Tags: mixing, production, logic-pro

Hey guys I was working on this project and suddenly the automation button is no longer showing on the look bar.

I can access it individually for each track or through the 'show automation' command on the mix menu.

Is there a way i can get to display it on the toolbar ? If I switch from MIDI to loops, it does show it.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?